# What does the penultimate argument in this ffmpeg command do?

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

```
ffmpeg -ss 2.5 -i input_vid.mp4 -vframes 1 -f image2 output_img.jpg
```

The above ffmpeg command creates a jpg image from the frame located 2.5 seconds into the input video file (to be used as a thumbnail for the video).

What role is `image2` playing here? I've seen several blog posts and SO answers that have `image2` or `image3` placed here as an argument to the `-vframes` flag, but I don't understand what it's used for. A temporary in-memory filename maybe?

I checked the [ffmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options), but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image2` is an image file [demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#details) used by ffmpeg to read the media file into packets (chunks).

---

From the [docs](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

The `image2` demuxer reads from a list of image files specified by a pattern. The pattern may contain a suffix which is used to automatically determine the format of the images contained in the files.

In this case, `output_img.jpg` is the pattern, and the demuxer establishes the format as JPEG, based on the file's extension.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 2.5 -i input_vid.mp4 -vframes 1 -f image2 output_img.jpg
#                                          |       |
#                                          \      /
#                                           ------ 
#                                             |
# as you can see, image2 is actually part of the argument "-f image2". This
# explicitly sets the container format. Some containers can have the same
# file extension, so this is a way to disambiguate.
```

[§ 5.4 Main options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

```
‘-f fmt (input/output)’

    Force input or output file format. The format is normally auto detected for input 
    files and guessed from the file extension for output files, so this option is not 
    needed in most cases.
```

Comment: Isn't the container format being set with the extension of `output_img.jpg`? And is `image2` an arbitrary variable name set in this command, or does it mean something universally?

Comment: @sgarza62 yes, normally the format is set by the extension, but as Ive said some formats use the same extension so you need to disambiguate. `ffmpeg -formats` for more info.